# Generating 10 bit signed integer

Tags: c, linux, random

this line `printf ("Random[%d]= %u\n", i, rand ());` generates a random integer mostly 1 bit, but when doing printf `("Random[%d]= %u\n", i, rand ()%1000000);` it generates 6 digits int,

when trying to generate a 10 digit int the error " warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long long int’ [-Wformat]" occurs.

so is there a way to generate a random 10 bit signed integer???

Comment: generate two integers, bitshift one of them to the left and combine with another?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mix the meaning of "bits" and "digits"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have passed sa "long long" or "unsigned long long" either explicitly or implicitly to the printf, which is why you get the warning -- but more on that later;

Generating a 10 digit random number, you will need to switch to 64 bit -- so long long;

```
unsigned long long randomvalue;
randomvalue = random();
randomvalue <<= 16; // just picked 16 at random
randomvalue ^= random();  // you could also use + but not "or";
randomvalue %= 10000000000ULL;
```

The warning you get is because you pass a value of type `long long` as the third argument to the `printf` function, but you still use `"%u"` as the format, which makes `printf` expect a value of type `unsigned int`.

To silence the warning, change the format to `"%lld"`.

It won't help you create a ten-digit number higher than `2147483647` though, as `rand` returns an `int` which so far is at most 32 bits, even on 64-bit platforms. Where the value `2147483647` comes from? The highest positive value if a signed 32-bit integer.

Comment: you presuppose a function `random()` that returns at least 16 random bits (and +1 for "do not use OR" -- I'm gonna sit back and let others chew on that one). The OP, however, used `rand()` and *vide* the confusion about Bits, Bytes, Digits it may be worth stressing that `rand()` is only *guaranteed* to be random at **15** bits (what RAND_MAX says depends entirely on the compiler (okay, *not* the compiler, but let's say it does for sake of brev.)).

Answer (score 1):

It does not fit in an int32 (check your platform to see how `int` is defined)

In an unsigned int32, the máximum value is 2^32 = 4,294,967,296. So when you do `rand % 10000000000`, `10000000000` is a `long` so `%` is computed as a `long` operation (which gives a result of such a type)

Comment: BTW: You should distinguish clearly between "bit" and "digit". They are the same only when dealing with binary format.